# Is there a way to spawn child processes in the Grails web framework?

Tags: grails

I'm trying to spawn a child process to do some backend cleanup work after a user performs an action. Can I just use the java.lang.Process class to create a process like I would in pure Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the [Executor](http://www.grails.org/plugin/executor) plugin or the [Quartz](http://www.grails.org/plugin/quartz) plugin (if you need them to perform on a schedule).

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need a process or would a thread suffice? If so, you can launch a new thread with:

```
Thread.start {
    // cleanup code goes here
}
```